# Click on object to do certain function

Tags: javascript, object, animation, canvas

I'm programming on JavaScript and basically what I'm supposed to do is to draw a face on a canvas and those faces have certain effects.

One of the effects I'm supposed to do is to click on the nose and it will change the face to an angry face. I have created objects for all the face parts (nose, eyes, etc.) and what I'm trying to do is that I want the function "angryFace" to be called when the nose is clicked. The nose is already an object.

Been stuck for a long time on this. Would appreciate it if someone could help! Uploaded the whole code down here. Thanks guys!

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>COM1008 Assignment 2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main1.css">
</head>

<main>
    <h1>COM 1008 Assignment 2</h1>
    <p>By Samuel Fung Chi Lun</p>
</main>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvasFrame" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
    <p>
        <button name="sadbutton" id="sadFace">Sad</button>
        <button name="angrybutton" id="angryFace">Angry</button>
        <button name="surprisedbutton" id="surprisedFace">Surprised</button>
        <button name="neutralbutton" id="neutralFace">Neutral</button>
    </p>
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasFrame');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        //Function to obtain x and y coordinates of mouse positions - Obtained from 20/11/2017 lecture slides
        function getMouseXY(e) {
            var boundingRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            var offsetX = boundingRect.left;
            var offsetY = boundingRect.top;
            var w = (boundingRect.width - canvas.width);
            var h = (boundingRect.height - canvas.height);
            offsetX += w;
            offsetY += h;
            var mx = Math.round(e.clientX - offsetX);
            var my = Math.round(e.clientY - offsetY);
            return { x: mx, y: my };
        }

        const BROWS_UP = 190;
        const BROWS_DOWN = 170;

        //Creating an object for left eye brow
        var leftEyeB = {
            draw: function (x1,brows_direction1,x2,brows_direction2) {
                context.beginPath();
                context.lineWidth = 18;
                context.moveTo(x1, brows_direction1);
                context.lineTo(x2, brows_direction2)
                context.stroke();
            }
        };
        //Creating an object for right eye brow
        var rightEyeB = {
            draw: function (x1,brows_direction1,x2,brows_direction2) {
                context.beginPath();
                context.lineWidth = 18;
                context.moveTo(x1, brows_direction1);
                context.lineTo(x2, brows_direction2)
                context.stroke();
            }
        };
        //Creating an object for the head
        var faceShape = {
            draw: function() {
                context.beginPath();
                context.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,0)"
                context.lineWidth = 3;
                context.arc(300, 300, 200, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                context.fill();
                context.stroke();
            }
        }
        //Creating an object for the eyes
        var eyes = {
            draw: function() {
                context.beginPath();
                context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
                context.moveTo(255, 250); //LeftEye
                context.arc(220, 250, 40, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                context.moveTo(415, 250);//Right Eye
                context.arc(380, 250, 40, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                context.fill();
                context.fill();
                context.stroke();
                context.beginPath();
                context.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
                context.moveTo(240, 250); //LeftPupil
                context.arc(220, 250, 15, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                context.moveTo(400, 250); //Right Pupil
                context.arc(380, 250, 15, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                context.fill();
                context.stroke();
            }
        }
        //Creating an object for the nose
        var nose = {
            draw: function() {
                context.beginPath();
                context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
                context.moveTo(300, 275);
                context.lineTo(275, 325);
                context.lineTo(325, 325);
                context.fill();
                context.closePath();
                context.stroke();
            }
        }
        //Creating an object for the mouth
        var mouth = {
            frown: function() {
                context.beginPath();
                context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
                context.moveTo(305, 427);//Mouth
                context.arc(305, 427, 80, 0, Math.PI, true); 
                context.fill();
                context.closePath();
                context.stroke();
            },
            circle: function() {
                context.beginPath();
                context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
                context.arc(300, 400, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                context.fill();
                context.stroke();
            },
            straight: function() {
                context.beginPath();
                context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
                context.rect(225, 390, 150, 20);//Mouth
                context.fill();
                context.stroke();
            }
        }
        //Drawing the sad face
        function sadFace() {
            faceShape.draw();
            eyes.draw();
            nose.draw();
            mouth.frown();
            leftEyeB.draw(175,BROWS_DOWN,265,BROWS_DOWN);
            rightEyeB.draw(335,BROWS_DOWN,425,BROWS_DOWN);
        }
        //Drawing the angry face
        function angryFace() {
            faceShape.draw();
            eyes.draw();
            nose.draw();
            mouth.frown();
            leftEyeB.draw(175,BROWS_DOWN,265,BROWS_UP);
            rightEyeB.draw(335,BROWS_UP,425,BROWS_DOWN);
        }
        //Drawing the surprised face
        function surprisedFace() {
            faceShape.draw();
            eyes.draw();
            nose.draw();
            mouth.circle();
            leftEyeB.draw(175,BROWS_UP,265,BROWS_DOWN);
            rightEyeB.draw(335,BROWS_DOWN,425,BROWS_UP);
        }
        //Drawing the neutral face
        function neutralFace() {
            faceShape.draw();
            eyes.draw();
            nose.draw();
            mouth.circle();
            leftEyeB.draw(175,BROWS_DOWN,265,BROWS_DOWN);
            rightEyeB.draw(335,BROWS_DOWN,425,BROWS_DOWN);
        }
        //Not sure how to properly do the bottom part. It does not work at all for the eyebrows one so please help!
        function effects() {
            //Click on the eyebrows to raise them
            if (mousePosition.x > x1 && mousePosition.x < x2 && mousePosition.y < BROWS_UP && mousePosition.y > BROWS_DOWN) {
                BROWS_UP += 20;
            }
            //Click on eye to show angry face
            if (mousePosition = on coordinates of the eye) {
                angryFace();
            }
            //Click on nose to show happy face
            if (mousePosition = on coordinates of the nose) {
                smileFace();
            }
        }

        canvas.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
            effects(evt);
        });

        neutralFace();

        //Linking the face functions to the buttons
        var angryButton = document.getElementById("angryFace");
        var sadButton = document.getElementById("sadFace");
        var surprisedButton = document.getElementById("surprisedFace");
        var neutralButton = document.getElementById("neutralFace");
        sadButton.addEventListener("click", sadFace);
        angryButton.addEventListener("click", angryFace);
        surprisedButton.addEventListener("click", surprisedFace);
        neutralButton.addEventListener("click", neutralFace);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you also share the related markup? I tried wrapping in snippet but its missing HTML elements

Comment: @Rajesh sorry,  have edited the post as such that it only shows the javascript part now. The HTML elements basically just draw up the buttons.

Comment: @Rajesh sorry I am new to Stack Overflow. I have added the whole code in the post along with some of my progress (which sadly does not work lol) in the post. Any luck?

Comment: Please notice `<>` icon in editor. It will open a popup. You will see sections for HTML, JS and CSS for their respective codes. Put it there and run. You will see output in bottom right section. Also, when you put code, dont put everything. Put only that much code that is required to simulate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you make face, for you, there are different objects(*say nose, eyes etc*). For DOM, there is only 1  object i.e. Canvas. So when you click, you are clicking on canvas and not nose.

So to achieve this, you will have to play with coordinates. You have to assume the position of every container and on click of canvas, check the coordinates. If the coordinates are within range of some object, fire necessary function.

```js
canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  var x = event.clientX, y = event.clientY;
  if(x> 280 && x <335 && y > 280 && y <335) {
    // nose is clicked.
    angryFace();
  }
  else {
    neutralFace();
  }
})
```

Following is a partial sample:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasFrame');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
//Function to obtain x and y coordinates of mouse positions - Obtained from 20/11/2017 lecture slides
function getMouseXY(e) {
  var boundingRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  var offsetX = boundingRect.left;
  var offsetY = boundingRect.top;
  var w = (boundingRect.width - canvas.width);
  var h = (boundingRect.height - canvas.height);
  offsetX += w;
  offsetY += h;
  var mx = Math.round(e.clientX - offsetX);
  var my = Math.round(e.clientY - offsetY);
  return {
    x: mx,
    y: my
  };
}

const BROWS_UP = 190;
const BROWS_DOWN = 170;

//Creating an object for left eye brow
var leftEyeB = {
  draw: function(x1, brows_direction1, x2, brows_direction2) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.lineWidth = 18;
    context.moveTo(x1, brows_direction1);
    context.lineTo(x2, brows_direction2)
    context.stroke();
  }
};
//Creating an object for right eye brow
var rightEyeB = {
  draw: function(x1, brows_direction1, x2, brows_direction2) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.lineWidth = 18;
    context.moveTo(x1, brows_direction1);
    context.lineTo(x2, brows_direction2)
    context.stroke();
  }
};
//Creating an object for the head
var faceShape = {
  draw: function() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,0)"
    context.lineWidth = 3;
    context.arc(300, 300, 200, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
  }
}
//Creating an object for the eyes
var eyes = {
  draw: function() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
    context.moveTo(255, 250); //LeftEye
    context.arc(220, 250, 40, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.moveTo(415, 250); //Right Eye
    context.arc(380, 250, 40, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.fill();
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
    context.moveTo(240, 250); //LeftPupil
    context.arc(220, 250, 15, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.moveTo(400, 250); //Right Pupil
    context.arc(380, 250, 15, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
  }
}
//Creating an object for the nose
var nose = {
  draw: function() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
    context.moveTo(300, 275);
    context.lineTo(275, 325);
    context.lineTo(325, 325);
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
    context.stroke();
  }
}
//Creating an object for the mouth
var mouth = {
  frown: function() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
    context.moveTo(305, 427); //Mouth
    context.arc(305, 427, 80, 0, Math.PI, true);
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
    context.stroke();
  },
  circle: function() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
    context.arc(300, 400, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
  },
  straight: function() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
    context.rect(225, 390, 150, 20); //Mouth
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
  }
}
//Drawing the sad face
function sadFace() {
  faceShape.draw();
  eyes.draw();
  nose.draw();
  mouth.frown();
  leftEyeB.draw(175, BROWS_DOWN, 265, BROWS_DOWN);
  rightEyeB.draw(335, BROWS_DOWN, 425, BROWS_DOWN);
}
//Drawing the angry face
function angryFace() {
  faceShape.draw();
  eyes.draw();
  nose.draw();
  mouth.frown();
  leftEyeB.draw(175, BROWS_DOWN, 265, BROWS_UP);
  rightEyeB.draw(335, BROWS_UP, 425, BROWS_DOWN);
}
//Drawing the surprised face
function surprisedFace() {
  faceShape.draw();
  eyes.draw();
  nose.draw();
  mouth.circle();
  leftEyeB.draw(175, BROWS_UP, 265, BROWS_DOWN);
  rightEyeB.draw(335, BROWS_DOWN, 425, BROWS_UP);
}
//Drawing the neutral face
function neutralFace() {
  faceShape.draw();
  eyes.draw();
  nose.draw();
  mouth.circle();
  leftEyeB.draw(175, BROWS_DOWN, 265, BROWS_DOWN);
  rightEyeB.draw(335, BROWS_DOWN, 425, BROWS_DOWN);
}

function effects() {
  mousePosition = getMouseXY(e);
  console.log(mousePosition);

}
neutralFace();

canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  var x = event.clientX, y = event.clientY;
  if(x> 280 && x <335 && y > 280 && y <335) {
    // nose is clicked.
    angryFace();
  }
  else {
    neutralFace();
  }
})

//Linking the face functions to the buttons
var angryButton = document.getElementById("angryFace");
var sadButton = document.getElementById("sadFace");
var surprisedButton = document.getElementById("surprisedFace");
var neutralButton = document.getElementById("neutralFace");
sadButton.addEventListener("click", sadFace);
angryButton.addEventListener("click", angryFace);
surprisedButton.addEventListener("click", surprisedFace);
neutralButton.addEventListener("click", neutralFace);
```

```html
<!-- This is not the original markup. This is a part of an edit to make the code executable. -->
<canvas id='canvasFrame' width=600 height=600></canvas>

<div>
  <button id="angryFace">Angry Face</button>
  <button id="sadFace">Sad Face</button>
  <button id="surprisedFace">Surprised Face</button>
  <button id="neutralFace">Neutral Face</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Right I sort of understand what you are doing. But since I have put all the coordinates of my nose into an object called nose. Is there anything I can do which is faster like if x coord is in nose then do this function?

Comment: As far as I can see, your nose object has a draw function which draws it. It does not specify any bounds

Comment: I see, because what I want to do next is for the eyebrows, if you click on it, you will raise the eyebrows. And as you can see, my eyebrows have different coordinates with different faces. What should I do?

Comment: You can have flags stating current face and based on it you can process. But canvas will not give you much option to play with.

Comment: Right, cause my assignment requires me to use canvas so I guess that's the tricky part haha.